# Read filename and break it down using using hyphens (-) and store in parts

Tags: batch-file

I have been given the task to read in a filename via a batch file and then divide it into three strings using `-` as break points.

I have `data1-data2-data3.txt`.

I can read the file and store the file location and file name without the `.txt` so I simply want to brake this down so it will read:

```
location=data1
filefrom=data2
fileto=data3
```

I am passing these to a VB script. It will be location of folder, the file to copy and file to copy to however I just wondered what I can use to break it down.

I have been playing with:

```
for /F "delims=-" %%i in ("%FILEPATH%")
```

But then what?

Comment: So data1-data2-data3 will become data1, data2 and data3 which as can place into strings and then pass out to vb as three arguments

Comment: for /F "delims=-" %%i in ("%FILEPATH%") do (
  set "FILENAME=%%~ni"
)

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f  "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%i in ('dir /b %filepath%') do (
 set location=%%~ni
 set filefrom=%%~nj
 set fileto=%%~nk
)
echo %location%, %filefrom%, %fileto%
```

Comment: Use `%%i %%j %%k` as the current way will break the terms if they contain periods.  Add `/a-d` to the dir command too, to exclude directories.